# how to do query with time var in sqlite

Tags: sql, vba, sqlite

Hello i need help doing this query,

the time var called `"dia"` have this value 2014-06-16 08:23:19
my code is this

```
cmd.CommandText = "select nombres, apellidos, cargo, id, dia, retraso_min 
from m_empleado as emp 
join asist as asis 
where emp.id = asis.id_emp 
  and  asis.dia > '" + des + "' 
  and  asis.dia < '" + has + "' "
```

If i put 
    select * from asist where dia > 10/06/2014
this works fine but... my query doesn't work 
"des" has the value of "10/06/2014"
and  "has" has the value of "30/12/2014
i try with between sentence but doesn't work for me
Any ideas?

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to buid sql commands. Use a parameterized query and let the database interpret the datetime parameter passed.

Comment: thanks do you have a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below shows how to use a parameterized query to search between two dates.
Keep in mind that in a parameterized query the value passed for the parameters should be of the exact datatype expected by the column subject of the search.

So, if your `dia` datatable field is a datetime field then you prepare two parameters of datetime type.
(`dia` and `has` variables should be datetime not strings)

```
DateTime dia = DateTime.Today;  // from 18 jun 2014 00:00 
DateTime has = DateTime.Today.AddMinutes(1439);  // to 18 Jun 2014 23:59

using(SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=D:\\temp\\mydb.db;Version=3"))
{
    cnn.Open();
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(@"select nombres, apellidos, cargo, id, dia,
                retraso_min from m_empleado as emp join asist as asis 
               where emp.id = asis.id_emp and  asis.dia between @ini and @fin", cnn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ini", dia);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fin", has);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dt.Load(reader);

}
```

Comment: it drops me this exception now:
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [HY000] parameter marker count incorrect

Comment: ODBC? Where did you get ODBC?. This example uses the ADO.NET provider for SQLite http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki (ODBC uses a different marker for parameters The question mark. `dia between ? and ?`)

Comment: Sorry i don't paste the entire code, my bad, Yes, it works all ok with the ? symbols THANK YOU!